# Edit a truetype font

Tags: windows, truetype

I'm trying to find a free tool (on windows ) that would enable me to change some settings on a TrueType font. Specifically, I'm trying to fix the following errors:

E1311 The macStyle bold bit doesn't match the name table's font subfamily string macStyle bold bit is set, but subfamily is Regular

W2000 The subfamily string is inconsistent with the style of the font OS/2.fsSelection bold bit is set, but subfamily string = 'Regular'

I can do that with fontographer, but would prefer to use something free. 
Fontforge doesn't seem to work with this font, when saved it corrupts the cyrillic letters in the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try [DoubleType](http://sourceforge.net/projects/doubletype/) which is an open source TrueType font editor.

There is also a small program called [eudcedit.exe](http://www.sino.uni-heidelberg.de/course_resources/s02/eudcedit/) which may be of help. It's pre-installed with XP and can be run from `Start > Run > eudcedit.exe`.

Other than these and FontForge, I don't know any *free* font editing programs.

Comment: i've tried it but found no way to open a .ttf font

Comment: Maybe `eudcedit` can help.

Comment: thanks, tried that too, but also can't open a .ttf font, can only link to it?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I guess this is the best there is. I went with a commercial product at the end.

Comment: site is down since 2012

Answer (score 0):

eudcedit is not a general purpose font editor. It is a tool for making a special kind of virtual font that is specific to Windows.

The easiest and least destructive way to do this kind of change would be with either ttx/fonttools (open source) or OTMaster (commercial tool). A full-on font editor will decompile and recompile the entire font and be more intrusive on other inner aspects of the font file.